# How to change Magento's "var" directory to other place in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I have installed Magento 2 in ubuntu guest / windows host in vagrant, but it is extremely slow. I think a simple change can improve performance, 
`How can I move my Magento's "var" directory to "/tmp/var" of ubuntu?`

Answer (score 3):

This is very likely going to change a bit before GA (a part of the reason it is not documented yet), but there is a short term solution if important to you. You can either in the `index.php` file incorporate:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$customDirs = [
    DirectoryList::CACHE => [DirectoryList::PATH => '/mnt/nfs/cache'],
    DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::PATH => '/mnt/nfs/media', DirectoryList::URL_PATH => '']
];
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, [Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS =>  $customDirs] + $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Or you can set it in an Apache environment variable.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"
    ServerName example.com
    SetEnv "MAGE_DIRS[cache][path]" "/home/www/appData/caches/example.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

If you look in https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Filesystem you can see a list of the various constants for path settings that can be overridden.

But a reminder that there may be changes in this area before GA. But I believe the above will work in beta1 and beta2.

Comment: both solutions only works for webapplication entry point. if you use the bin/console all commands will not have the cache file changes