# MAGE_DIRS bootstrap parameters in CLI

Tags: magento2, url, magento-2.1, indexing, cli

In `pub/index.php`, the following code is used to set change URLs for media and static assets to omit "/pub":

```
$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
    DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
    DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
    DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
    DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
];
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

Unfortunately in CLI scripts (`bin/magento`) there is nothing like this.

I found the class `Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener` with the following code:

```
$initParams = $application->getServiceManager()->get(self::BOOTSTRAP_PARAM);
$directoryList = $this->createDirectoryList($initParams);
```

But I don't understand where this Zend Service Manager retrieves the data and how it might be possible to influence it.

My concrete problem is that an indexer has to generate full URLs and currently does it like `http://magento.local/pub/media/...`, where I need it to be `http://magento.local/media/...`

**How can I tell the CLI that my virtual host points to `pub` and "pub" should not be part of URLs?**

Ideally this should work without having to rely on additional CLI parameters or environment variables.

Comment: This has recently been reported as a bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8868

Comment: I found that you can set this using an argument like `--magento-init-params=MAGE_DIRS[media][uri]=media`. This actually works for all commands (evident by stepping through code), but commands outside `setup:` namespace incorrectly give an error that the option does not exist.

Comment: @ScottSB Not exactly what I was hoping for, but still an interesting find, thanks for that!

Answer (score 7):

After much travail, I found a solution using environment variables, which I know isn't what you wanted. You can set the parameters using environment variables like this (replacing `$APP_ROOT` with your actual Magento root):

```bash
env \
    "MAGE_DIRS[base][path]=$APP_ROOT" \
    "MAGE_DIRS[pub][uri]=" \
    "MAGE_DIRS[media][uri]=media" \
    "MAGE_DIRS[static][uri]=static" \
    "MAGE_DIRS[upload][uri]=media/upload" \
    bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Note that it's necessary to specify the base path as above because when you use environment variables, your `MAGE_DIRS` definition overwrites the initial default that includes that. It will, however, get merged with the fuller default config in `\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList`.

Credit to this answer from the chief architect himself for putting me on the scent:

[How to change Magento's "var" directory to other place in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49525/how-to-change-magentos-var-directory-to-other-place-in-magento-2)

Comment: How do you use environment variables? Are these getting added into VHOST like the referenced answer?

Comment: @harri I don't understand your question. Because this talking about a CLI command, a vhost isn't relevant, as the web server isn't involved. The environment variables are passed right on the command line as illustrated (arguments to `env` in the format `FOO=bar` get set as environment variables for the command at the end, in this case `bin/magento`).

Comment: Ah for my i'm getting this issue with a method run via cron so not sure if there is a way to wack this in with my bin/magento cron:run in crontab?

Comment: Just take what I have in the answer and replace `indexer:reindex` with `cron:run` (and still update $APP_ROOT too of course). Then drop that whole thing into the crontab. Not sure if crontab will like the newlines, so you could just replace them with spaces (removing the trailing backslashes in that case).

Comment: I think better solution is here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/174503/41325

Comment: That other answer violates Magento's best practice and is likely to break when you upgrade Magento. See my comment on that answer for details.

Comment: @ScottBuchanan, in which file we need to make the change?

Comment: @jafarpinjar You would use this as the call in your crontab. It doesn't go inside a Magento code file.

Comment: @ScottBuchanan, I am still not clear, can you pls elaborate

Comment: @jafarpinjar If you're not familiar with crontab, that's beyond the scope of this question and more than I can explain here. However, in short, this is a manual modification to the crontab entries you presumably created following the instructions here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#create-the-magento-crontab

Comment: Actually, I just remembered this question was more general, about CLI commands in general, not specific to cron. It applies to cron, but not just to cron. You would use the command prefix from `env` up to `bin/magento` to execute whatever CLI command you're executing, wherever you're executing it from.

Answer (score 6):

Another, simpler option is to simply hard-code the media path in the store config under Stores > Configuration > Web to:

```
{{unsecure_base_url}}media/
```

and

```
{{secure_base_url}}media/
```

Due credit to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9111#issuecomment-292002922

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to set **`MAGE_DIRS`** via CLI, just copy

```
/vendor/magento/framework/App/Filesystem/DirectoryList.php
```

to

```
/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Filesystem/DirectoryList.php
```

And now you can change default directory of all internal files.

Comment: thx this helped me to change the cache folder for cli and webapp  ;D

Comment: Actually I belive this is the best solution of this problem. Official Magento guide recommends to use /lib/internal to customize the core.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/framework.html#highlights-of-magento-framework

Comment: @A.Maksymiuk I believe you are misunderstanding that page. It is noting that the code there may be useful for extension developers, but it is *not* recommending customizing core directly there. Earlier on the page it says: "You should never modify Framework files, although if you are extending Magento, you must know how to call Framework libraries."